# how to display the json array value in html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using the following jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#serviceId").change(function(){
        var service_id=$("#serviceId").val();

            $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/pranasInventory/get_service_amount",
                    data:{service_id:service_id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('#amount').append(data);
                    },

                });
        });
        });
</script>
```

I got the follwing responce in html input field

```
<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount">[{"service_amount":"2000000"}]</input>

I want to display the service_amount in input value field.
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$('#amount').val( data[0].service_amount );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of append the `data` object to input control, you should assign value to input control. You can try any one code

```
$('#amount').val(data[0].service_amount );
```

or

```
$('#amount').val(data[0]["service_amount"]);
```